# Rails form_for assistance: param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having an annoying problem with my form_for method while creating forums. Everytime I try to submit a forum for creation, I receive this error from Rails.`param is missing or the value is empty: forum`

The problem is in my forums_param method:

```
def forum_params
  params.require(:forum).permit(:id, :name, :position)
end
```

The forum part does not exist. The code below is my form for the view:

```
well.span11
  .span7
    = form_for @forum, url: forums_path, html: { method: :post } do |f|
      = render partial: "form", locals: { f: f }
      .actions
        = submit_tag 'Create', { class: 'btn btn-primary btn-small' }
.clear
```

And the partial that it renders:

```
 %fieldset
  %div{class: 'control-group'}
    = label_tag :title, "Title (required)", class: 'control-label required'
    %div{class: 'controls'}
      = text_field_tag :name, nil, class: 'span8'
    - if @forum.errors[:name]
      %p{class: 'error'}#{@forum.errors[:name]}

  %div{class: 'control-group'}
    = label_tag :position, "Position", class: 'control-label'
    %div{class: 'controls'}
      = text_field_tag :position, nil, size: 5

  %div{class: 'control-group'}
    = label_tag :description, "Description", class: 'control-label'
    %div{class: 'controls'}
      = text_area_tag :description, nil, rows: 10, class: 'span10'
```

Below is the controller code:

```
  def new
    @forum = Forum.new
  end

  def create
    @forum = Forum.new(forum_params)
    if @forum.save
      redirect_to forums_path, flash: { success: t('.success') }
    else
      redirect_to forums_path, flash: { error: t('.error') }
    end
  end
```

I'm not sure what is going on here. I have already implemented the recommendations described under these posts.

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083673/actioncontrollerparametermissing-param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984608/rails-4-0-param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty)

[Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681280/param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty)

What is the problem here? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the url / path of the page that you are getting this error on?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're missing a bunch of stuff as it goes from view to controller. You have the description field, title etc.. and these aren't being factored into the `forum_params`

If the user can add these and change them, they must be included in strong params. I don't think id should be in there though... user shouldn't be allowed to change the id. That should be created by AR when the record is created.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here appears to be your usage of `<foo>_tag` instead of `f.<foo>_field`.

When you use `<foo>_tag`, a literal tag with the attributes you gave it appears in the DOM.

**`text_field_tag` example:**

```
text_field_tag 'title'
# => <input id="title" name="title" type="text" />
```

Based on an example from the docs. Source: [the Ruby on Rails API docs for text_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag)

Whereas, when you use `f.<foo>_field`, the `name` attribute is namespaced under the model name.

**`f.text_field` example:**

```
text_field(:post, :title, size: 20)
# => <input type="text" id="post_title" name="post[title]" size="20" value="#{@post.title}" />
```

Source: [the Ruby on Rails API docs for text_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field)

**Slightly more in-depth explanation**

With the examples above, when the first is submitted, the params look like:

```
{ ..., "title" => "user's input", ... }
```

You can see from this that if your controller tries to get `:post` out of this parameters hash, it is `nil`, and it throws the error you encountered.

The params for the second example in the first section look like:

```
{ ..., "post" => {"title" => "user's input", ... }, ... }
```

When the controller tries to get `:post` out of this hash, it gets the sub-hash containing `title` (and any other form fields).

I hope this solves your problem!